# Rails API Returns Too Much Time Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index endpoint API set up. This API controller doesn't inherit from Application Controller.

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_with @projects
end
```

Querying it returns:

[{"id":7,"name":"Something","location":"United States","user_id":54,"created_at":
{"^o":"ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone","utc": `//don't need` {"^t":1513746428.835358000},"time":null,"time_zone": `//don't need`

The problem is that it returns a whole lot of timezone info in every `project` that slows down the app.

How can I return only the created_at timestamp in UTC as it is seen in the PG database without the timezone clutter?

Comment: What do you mean by "slows down the app?" Have you profiled the time it takes?

Comment: Rails has to render too many timezone characters.. that slows it down if there is a lot of info returned

Comment: OK, your issue isn't with the database extraction but with the formatting. I would generally address this in the view, so I'll post an example.

Comment: There is no view though. This is API only and Rails takes too long to return the JSON response because the JSON has too much unneeded data, nested timezones etc

Comment: respond_with still invokes a jbuilder template if present, otherwise it will use some sort of default serialization, which appears not to be the default you want. So you can solve this by specifying a template.

Comment: Just realized that you may be using an older version Rails, perhaps? I think DateTime didn't always have an as_json method and the default serialization could have, at some point, been more unfortunate?

Comment: That's a good guess, but i'm on Rails 5.02, pg 9.5.. I am using OJ for JSON serialization. Maybe that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to call:

```
Project.where(company_id: @current_company.id).as_json
```

before rendering the JSON.

`respond_with` by itself used the extra time zone transitions

Answer (score 1):

In your select query:

```
Select (created_at at time zone 'pst') as created_at from ...
```

Comment: Thanks but then you have to specify the columns. Is there a solution where I wouldn't have to use `select` to specify the columns and keep using `Project.all`?

Comment: try in your config/application.rb

   `config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc # Or :local`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to achieve is controlled formatting of your json.

If that's the case, I think you want to create a json view. I don't use the responders gem, so there may some nuance I'm not seeing, but generally you'd create a file to specify what you want to be returned.

In index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.array! @projects, :id, :name, :location, :user_id, :created_at
```

The way my project is configured, created_at shows up like this: `"created_at":"2017-12-17T10:09:12.141Z"`. However, it's possible you'll still have an issue depending on the serialization behavior of that ActiveSupport class. If so, you can customize the output further by invoking a method:

```
json.array! @projects do |project|
  json.extract! project, :id, :name, :location, :user_id
  json.created_at project.created_at.utc
  # Or perhaps something like:
  #   json.created_at project.created_at.in_time_zone.as_json
end
```

If your use case makes jbuilder inappropriate, you can use a different serializer.

ActiveModel::Serializer is a common choice; you can control the attributes that are serialized, and there are mechanisms for controlling how those attributes are serialized as well.

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :location :created_at
  belongs_to :user
end
```

There's an important caveat, though: I can't quite reproduce your issue. In a brand-new, minimalist rails api project I created, the returned json from `render json: @projects, status: :ok` (without jbuilder, nothing custom) returns "created_at":"2018-02-28T02:31:10.603Z" for me, so I think you need to figure out how the ActiveSupport TimeWithZone instance is being inserted into your serialization format. It may be something about your app's configuration that's causing that.